# Firing ng-change only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to call a function from ng-change on an input of type text only once, and on the first call it sets a boolean value to true, after that i want to disable the ng-change from firing whenever the input changes because all i need to do is to change a boolean to true

here is the controller

```
angular.module("app",[]).controller('FieldCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.Value = '';
  $scope.IsRequired = true;
  $scope.HasBeenForTheFirstTime = false;

  $scope.ValueChanged = function() {
    $scope.HasBeenForTheFirstTime = true;
    console.log("isFired");
  };
}]);
```

and the html simply

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="Value"
       value="{{Value}}"  
       ng-change="ValueChanged()">
```

one more thing is, is using ng-change the right thing in this case?

Comment: You can also use $scope.$watch for tracking changes for the ng-model.

Answer (score 0):

Using $watch...

```
angular.module("app",[]).controller('FieldCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
      $scope.Value = '';
      $scope.IsRequired = true;
      $scope.HasBeenEditedBefore = false;


      $scope.UnWatch = $scope.$watch("Value",function(){
        if($scope.Value.length > 0)
        {
            $scope.HasBeenEditedBefore = true;
            $scope.UnWatch(); 
        }
      });

    }]);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can remove $scope.ValueChanged function and use the following code is enough.

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="Value"
       value="{{Value}}"  
       ng-change="HasBeenForTheFirstTime=true" />
```

Comment: but thats no different you are assigning true to true and the event gets fired

Comment: it is when you have more logic, i think watch is the right way then unwatch

Comment: If you have more logic then just check this condition at the start in function and return. Else do a watch on the variable, and you can de register a watch.